# How to match html elements in an array to html elements in a each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to loop thru li elements of a certain class and see if these exist in an array of parent elements.
These constitute a menu with submenus which may have further submenus.

I can do it on the element clicked on, which fires the event, but need help with matching each iterated element against those in the array.

I have added the HTML in the Edit.

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu a.HasDropDown').on("click", function(e) {
  var current = $(this);
  var Parents = $(this).parents();
  var i = 0;

  $(this).parent().next('ul').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.dropdown-submenu a.clicked').each(function() {
    // Omit the clicked on element and it's parent menu and the next parent menu etc, closing & setting only the others
    for (var i = 0; i < Parents.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).text() == $(Parents[i]).text()) {
        alert("parent found");
      }
    }
    if ($(current).text() == $(this).text() || $(this) == Parents[i]) {
      alert(" Same");
    } else {
      // Hide all these other menus
      //$(current).parent().next().slideToggle(200);
    }
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-left">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown-menu show" style="color: gainsboro; display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span> Menu
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu show" style="background: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important; width: 20%;">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <span>
      <a class="HasDropDown dropdown-toggle clicked" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="#">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span> Administration
          </a>
          </span>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <span>
        <a class="HasDropDown dropdown-toggle" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="#">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span> Lookup Tables
              </a>
              </span>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="/Country/List">
          Countries
         </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="/City/List">
          Cities
         </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <span>
        <a class="HasDropDown dropdown-toggle" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="#">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span> Security
              </a>
              </span>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="/IdentityComponent">
          Users
         </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="/identitycomponentpermission">
          Roles
         </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <span>
        <a class="HasDropDown dropdown-toggle" style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="#">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></span> Debtors
              </a>
              </span>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a style="color: gainsboro; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34) !important;" href="/Debtor/List">
          Debtors
         </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: use `array.includes(loopvalue)`. This will return true or false. You don't have to run another loop inside `.each()`. Look here  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Comment: I tried the array.includes, as Parents.includes($(this)) but I get an error, "Object does not support method or object  'includes'

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: I have now included the html.

Comment: We are using the latest jquery version.

Comment: Could you explain the expected result ? Because, given your example, i don't get your issue

Comment: If the user clicks on some other menu or submenu which has 'HasDropDown', I want to close all other menus except the one clicked on and then it's direct parent(s). So if administration is open and beneath it, 'Lookup Tables' is open and the user clicks on 'Security'  (under 'Administration' ) or one of the 1st level other dropdown menus eg. 'Debtors' I need to close any others which are open, as currently they display on top of each other.